# How do I configure the Block Access module?

Tags: blocks

I want to use the *Block Access* module, but I don't know how to configure the module. I tried to find some tutorials or user manuals but I couldn't. I installed and enabled the module end I can change the permissions in the /admin/people/permissions page. I want to allow permission to a specific user role to  Edit own block content.

How can I give the block ownership to a specific user role?

Answer (score 2):

This module is an administrative level module. You can use it to configure who can create/administer/view/etc blocks. For instance, what I did to realize what the module does, logged in as admin:

1. Install and enable the module Block Access
2. Create a new role, lets say testadmin, and grant to it every permission
3. Create a new user, lets say testuser, with that role
4. Log in with user testuser and create a dummy block
5. Log in again as admin
6. Edit the permissions of the role testadmin and deselect the permissions "Administer block access settings" and "Create blocks", under the section "Block Access" (these permissions are added by the Block Access module)
7. Log in again as testuser and try to create another dummy block
8. End of the exercise, because now the user testuser can't create blocks...

In this exercise I only used two permissions, but the module Block Access implements a lot more!